# Amesim FMU initialization issue

Tags: simulink, fmi

I have a HU submodels FMU that is not running in a Simulink model.
I use Matlab2020b, FMIkit2.7 and the FMU created with Amesim 2019.1.

This is the error message:

```
AME_LIC_CACHE_INIT set to 100
Impossible to open file 'pV/pV_FrontAxle_Variant1.txt'.
Impossible to open file 'pV/pV_FrontAxle_Variant1.txt'.
Fatal error in FXA001 instance 1.
Terminating the program.
Simcenter Amesim model: initialization failed.
Failed to exit initialization mode
Failed to exit initialization mode. The FMU crashed (exception code: UNKOWN_EXEPTION_CODE).
```

I give 2 parameter in .txt file for the FXA001. It is worked in older versions of the model.
I tried to give the full path, copy the files to the folder where the model was and still not found.

Has anyone ever had such an issue?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tested with other importers like FMU-Check or fmpy?
Genererally I recommend to contact your Siemens PLM Support for AMESim.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, this issue might happen if the two text files do not have a header mentioning the *Amesim* table format they use.
For example for a so-called “1D” table:

#Table format: 1D

Otherwise the files may not be embedded properly when exporting the FMU.